LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "AB
I encountered this error when compiling my Tex file, the compiler used was pdfLaTex:
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.587 export class «entity.
                            name» {
The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool

The reason is probably that I need to use the special symbols « and » in formulas and listings code blocks, but these two symbols cannot be processed correctly, and I don’t know which input encoding to use to solve this problem.
Of course, if the compiler is changed to LuaLaTex, it can be solved, but due to limitations, I can only use pdfLaTeX.
Has anyone encountered this situation? Thank you for your help!

The issue is not the symbol per se, but the encoding of the source: it is being interpreted as UTF-8, but that's not what you have.

Show a small but complete example with the failure.

either your original source is not in UTF-8 or you have used a command (such as \uppercase in a way that breaks the UTF-8 encoding by changing individual bytes in an inappropriate way, but you have not given enough information to show what is happening.

(always use a code block not a quotation for error messages in posts here, so line endings are preserved)

Thanks for your help and reminders. I have confirmed that the file is saved as UTF-8 in vscode. I compiled it in overleaf, and each error appears where I use « or » in listings or formulas. The compilation error information is as follows:```See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.590 ...   «attr.name»: «findType(attr.type)»``` I wrote this sentence «attr.name»: «findType(attr.type)»in a listings code block

you really are not supplying any information. The handling of « in general text or listings or math are all completely different and you have provided no example code and only shown fragments of error message. By default listings doesn't support UTF-8 see the listingsutf8 package for a possible solution but without any example it is hard to say if that is what you are looking for, (It certainly will not help with math mode formulae)

« is Unicode U+00AB
In UTF-8 that is the byte sequence C2 AB. The byte AB (which would represent « in the 8-bit latin-1 encoding) should never appear as a leading byte in UTF-8.
You don't show the error message in the question (just the following help text) nor show an example.
With the document
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
«attr.name»
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

LaTeX gives the error
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\lst@FillFixed@).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 «attr.
           name»
?

Only if you scroll past that do you get the error that you suggest in the title.
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "AB.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 «attr.
           name»
?

TeX only recovers from errors enough to try to syntax check the remaining document it does not try to recover any reasnable state so later errors are often spurious, and you should only really consider the first.
Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?
suggests

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    literate={«}{{\guillemetleft}}1 {»}{{\guillemetright}}1 
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
«attr.name»
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your help！I am a latex beginner, please forgive me for not being clear in some places.
